# Node.js application quits if other server is unreachable. How do I prevent my application from stopping?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an application that regularly checks in with a remote server to check in for new versions of software.  It's my first attempt in node.js so please bear with me.
When the server is up and running, the program runs totally fine.
However, when the server is not running, the program quits with the error:

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

From what I've read, I believe I have set up my code to handle errors correctly, by including a response.on('error', ...) part of my callback.
However, as you can see from the error, it's not giving me the error console.logs that I tried to set up.
Here's the part of my code that is not working, I can include other parts if need be, it's just a pretty big application at this point:

```
var index = require ("./index");
var http = require ('http');
var fs = require ("fs");

var apps = [{
  "name":"IDSocket",
  "localVersion": "",
  "hostVersion": "",
  "downloadURL": ""
},
{
  "name": "X-Wing vs. Tie Fighter",
  "localVersion": "4.2.1",
  "hostVersion": "",
  "downloadURL": ""
}]

//checks host server for host version, stores as json object
function checkHost(hostinfo){
  callback1 = function(response) {
    var str = '';
    var hostObject;

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
    });

    response.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + err.message);
      hostObject = "why, error? " + err.message
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      hostObject = str;
      hostObject = JSON.parse(hostObject);
      apps[0]["hostVersion"] = hostObject[0]["version"];
      apps[0]["downloadURL"] = hostObject[0]["downloadURL"];
      apps[1]["hostVersion"] = hostObject[1]["version"]
      apps[1]["downloadURL"] = hostObject[1]["downloadURL"]
      console.log(apps[0]["hostVersion"] + ": recieved IDSocket host version");
      index.everyFourHours();
    });
  }

  http.request(hostinfo, callback1).end();

};
```

Thanks in advance for any helping me understand what's going on here!

EDIT:
things I have tried so far:

try  block on both the http.request line as well as the whole callback function with catch blocks that just console.log the error

process.on('uncaughtException'

domain.create & domain.run

Comment: What you've presented here looks right to me, so it might be somewhere else in your code that's causing the problem. This article is a pretty good overview on error handling in Node: http://strongloop.com/strongblog/robust-node-applications-error-handling/

Comment: try catch on the exception ? :}

Comment: @Pogrindis I'm not exactly sure what you mean, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: do a try{}catch(){} around the checking process instead of throwing an error.. They're a little more expensive but will ensure the service doesn't fatally collapse..

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding an error handler to instance of your `http.request`.

For example, you could change your `http.request` call to:

```
var req = http.request(hostinfo, callback1);
req.on('error', function(err) { console.log("ERROR: " + err.message); });
req.end();
```

Read [here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) for more info.

Comment: I tried this, and my application still shuts down, but now with "ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED"

Comment: What is the value of `hostinfo` that you are passing to the `http.request`?

Comment: var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/versions.json',
    port: 3000
  };

Comment: It downloads from the host fine when I have the server up

Comment: OK so if the server is down, the request emits an error and now you are catching it with `req.on`. Is that not the intended behaviour? What do you want/expect to be happening?

Comment: he's catching it, but the `throw` from sindie events.js is still killing the application. or, at least that's how i understand it.

Comment: @bhimley85: Can you try handling error both on request and response. Your sample code above only shows you catching error on response. Once you've tried that and it still fails please update your sample code so that people who want to answer this question can see that you've tried it.